# How to get the exact page number of the table

Tags: tables, page-numbering

I used `\thepage` for printing the current page number, here my table placed on page 2 but the page number I got in output is 1.  Refer the attached image. Please suggest how to get the exact page number of the table. Please find my code below.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

 Infrared (IR) observations are crucial for the physical and
thermal characterization of distant objects which are typically too
small to be resolved even by the largest ground or space telescopes.
The thermal emission measurements allow one to determine accurate
radiometric size and albedo information, but they also put
constraints on the object's thermal properties and spin-axis
orientations. Albedos derived from thermal data are important to
interpret broadband colors and NIR spectral data. The
submillimeter/millimeter (submm/mm)-range emission originates from a
few millimeters below the surface and can be used to determine the
object's long-wavelength emissivity. A recent new approach is to
combine multidata information (occultations, thermal,
high-resolution imaging, etc.) to perform more sophisticated
physical and thermal characterization of Trans-Neptunian objects
(TNOs) and Centaurs, and to constrain properties which are otherwise
not accessible, for example, the object's spin-axis orientation. At
the same time, the multidisciplinary approach allows one to impro[![enter image description here][1]][1]ve
and extend model techniques, for example, the verification of
radiometric sizes via occultation results.

\begin{table}
\caption{Table caption Page number of this table: \thepage}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\textbf{Column one head} & \textbf{Column two head}\\
\hline
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
Column one & Column 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

 Infrared (IR) observations are crucial for the physical and
thermal characterization of distant objects which are typically too
small to be resolved even by the largest ground or space telescopes.
The thermal emission measurements allow one to determine accurate
radiometric size and albedo information, but they also put
constraints on the object's thermal properties and spin-axis
orientations. Albedos derived from thermal data are important to
interpret broadband colors and NIR spectral data. The
submillimeter/millimeter (submm/mm)-range emission originates from a
few millimeters below the surface and can be used to determine the
object's long-wavelength emissivity. A recent new approach is to
combine multidata information (occultations, thermal,
high-resolution imaging, etc.) to perform more sophisticated
physical and thermal characterization of Trans-Neptunian objects
(TNOs) and Centaurs, and to constrain properties which are otherwise
not accessible, for example, the object's spin-axis orientation. At
the same time, the multidisciplinary approach allows one to improve
and extend model techniques, for example, the verification of
radiometric sizes via occultation results.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `\label{table-XYZ}` in the table, you can use:

```
See table~\ref{table-xyz} on page~\pageref{table-XYZ}.
```

As suggested in the comments, the `\label{}` command in the table (how you reference the table in the .tex) should be something like the following:

```
% Somewhere in your document you place your table, similar to this:
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{This is a nice table}
\begin{tabular}{}
% the table content goes here
\end{tabular}
% Then you place the \label like this
\label{tab:label}
\end{table}
```